# simple C++ project samples

Tags: c++, projects-and-solutions, sample

Im trying to learn OOP but I need to see some real case scenarios of using C++. For me, as a beginner in programming internet is too big and the book is too few examples. All I find on the source repositories are large projects or too few details.

Can you give me a link to some c++ projects which are good for beginners? It will be great if the samples have some details about good practices.

maybe some universities are hosting such projects or maybe you know a webpage with samples and contests about how to program in C++ and it is good for beginners.

Comment: What book are you using?  It sounds like you might find something better on [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Such thing would be cool for other languages too... Often a book or a documentation are just explaining the code with trivial (non reallife) examples which are too short or they've divided the original project too much. A simple project with ~5 classes which do trivial things and are in some way related to each other would be perfect.

Comment: it is a book written  in my native language. Ty for the tip. I'll see what can i have/buy from that list

Comment: indeed MOnsDar. That's my problem. Besides the concepts I have nothing. I need real life scenarios to see, duplicate, modify and learn. Sorry, but this is how i can learn. :(

Comment: just implement something that interest you. That's the best way to learn. Just use books and tutorials as references. Use them as you build your tool(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting at the [C++ Language Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).  There are lots of good examples there, including a section on OOP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn OOP try looking at these lecture videos, they are fantastic for beginners its in Java but you shouldnt limit yourself to C++ as a learning platform.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMDCCdjyW8

Comment: TY, but atm I'll stay with C++ on windows using eclipse-cdt IDE. I'm not sure if eclipse is the best tool for a beginner yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've found such a sample project.
The problem is that it is documented well, but the documentation-language is German. There additionally are some classnames which are German etc. There also is no documentation like a class diagram included.

I've written that project some months ago to show a new apprentice some C++ and some object-oriented tasks. Hope its not too complex for your purposes.

This example is not perfect, but perhaps it is what you're searching or other users could get a better idea of what is questioned.

[Download (Rapidshare.com)](http://rapidshare.com/files/425964148/SampleProject.tar.gz)

PS: How should someone upload such things in the future? There are several source-files included (pastebin wouldn't be good for something like that). I wouldn't use Sourceforge for such a project. Is there something like a stackoverflow-attachment feature?

Comment: ty! thats soo cool idea. My native language is italian but german language is on my "to learn list" bc i like your country too.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this C++ book:  [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481) which has good practice exercises and there is also a [Answer book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309939) for the exercise problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the fabulous lectures / books, I'd encourage you to practice a few times. I enjoy using the [bowling kata](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata) exercise for this.  Technically, this is a refactoring exercise but it is quite fun and I believe effective.

Answer (score 0):

I did a screencast of the bowling game in C++ earlier this week.  You can watch it here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200804075400/http://cheezyworld.com/2011/01/12/bowling-game-in-c/